# Different styles for childs before and after specifed element using jQuery and CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to set special styles for `li.done` depending on whether they are before or after `li.current`. How can I do that using jQuery or CSS?

```css
ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

ul li {
  display:inline-table;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  color: #ddd;
  background-color: #bbb;
  margin: 0;
}
.done {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #aaa
}
.current {
  background-color: #99f;
  color: #dee
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="done">step 1</li>
<li class="done">step 2</li>
<li class="current">step 3</li>
<li class="done">step 4</li>
<li>step 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In question you say **...for those after 'li.current'.** and in comment **...that are before li.current**, please explan more or add an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I need set different style for li.done elements that are before li.current and different styles for those li.done elements that are after li.current...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this just with CSS by using the `~` selector. From the [W3 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators):

> **General sibling combinator**
>
> The general sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~) character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the document tree and the element represented by the first sequence precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the second one.

That means that you could set the styles for the `.done` that happen after `.current` by applying the selector: `.current ~ .done`.

One example:

```css
ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

ul li {
    display:inline-table;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    color: #ddd;
    background-color: #bbb;
    margin: 0;
}
.done {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #aaa
}
.current {
    background-color: #99f;
    color: #dee
}

.current ~ .done { 
  background-color:#f99; 
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="done">step 1</li>
    <li class="done">step 2</li>
    <li class="current">step 3</li>
    <li class="done">step 4</li>
    <li class="done">step 5</li>
    <li>step 6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you vary much. This rocks! If some will be not right i came here back to ask :P

Comment: Cool - CSS only! That should be prefered over JS. Good browser support as well. Here is a link to it on W3C Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at jQuerys `.prevAll()` and `.nextAll()`.

```
var current = $(".current");
current.prevAll(".done").addClass("before");
current.nextAll(".done").addclass("after");
```

Please note that you will have to redo this every time you change the current element.

The documentation can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) and [here](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).

Comment: But what with last element who don't have 'done' class? With nextAll() he also be with this special style? is not?

Comment: You can add a selector as parameter: `nextAll(".done")`. Did not do so because I was unsure of what the desired result was.

Comment: OK i test this also... but answer of @Alvaro Montoro now is the winner :)

Comment: When you can do something easily without JS relying only on CSS you should do so. So good choice.